# Wagtail app wagalytics show an 500 Error on console /admin/analytics/token/ 500

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

Am integrating Wagtail and Google Analytics with the  app wagalytics gives  me  /admin/analytics/token/ 500 () and  the settings i used  as indicated on the ReadMe

GA_KEY_FILEPATH = 'project-6408cf73f290.json'

GA_KEY_CONTENT = 'key  content'

GA_VIEW_ID = 'ga:173531812'

Kindly where  am i  going wrong ?

This is  the only  error shown  when i put the JSON  key contents with `GA_KEY_CONTENT = '{"type": "service_account",...'`

```
    AttributeError at /admin/analytics/token/
'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/analytics/token/
Django Version: 1.11.11
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Please include the full error message (including stack trace if available).

Comment: am  just getting 500 error in terminal

Comment: Try right-clicking on the URL in the console, then 'open in new tab'.

Comment: @gasman kindly  check the edit i  made  on the  error  i get

Answer (score 1):

The value of `GA_KEY_CONTENT` should be the *contents* of your JSON key, not a reference to the location.

Comment: do you have an example as i  am  getting  'dict' object has no attribute 'replace' error

Comment: You still need to surround the value in quotes to make it a string: `GA_KEY_CONTENT = '{"web":{"client_id":".....}'`

Comment: @gasman  i get this error  Error at /admin/analytics/token/
[('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line')] ,  kindly how do i resolve it